# When i need to import promise like const promise = require ('promise') to have the property of .then

Tags: node.js, promise

I am new to node js. I am in a great confusion in using promise property of node js. Some of example shows when i need to use promise i need to require promise but some of example says does not like that.

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const assert = require('assert');
const dboper = require('./operation');
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/';
const dbname = 'conFusion';

MongoClient.connect(url)

        .then((client) => {

        console.log('Connected correctly to server');
        const db = client.db(dbname);

        dboper.insertDocument(db, { name: "Vadonut", description: "Test"},"dishes")
            .then((result) => {
                console.log("Insert Document:\n", result.ops);

                return dboper.findDocuments(db, "dishes");
            })
            .then((docs) => {
                console.log("Found Documents:\n", docs);

                return dboper.updateDocument(db, { name: "Vadonut" }, { description: "Updated Test" }, "dishes");

            })
            .then((result) => {
                console.log("Updated Document:\n", result.result);

                return dboper.findDocuments(db, "dishes");
            })
            .then((docs) => {
                console.log("Found Updated Documents:\n", docs);

                return db.dropCollection("dishes");
            })
            .then((result) => {
                console.log("Dropped Collection: ", result);

                return client.close();
            })

})
.catch((err) => console.log(err));

Here .then is used in chained manner. But no promise word is used here. 

function readFile(data){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        fs.readFile(data, function(err, buf) {
            if(err){
                console.log("Error : "+ err);
                reject("Rejected");
            }
            else{
                a = buf.toString();
                console.log(a);
                resolve();
            }   
          });    
    });  
}

readFile(text)
    .then(()=>{
        const origin = fs.createReadStream('1.txt', {flags: 'r'});
        const destination = fs.createWriteStream('input.txt', {flags: 'w+'});    
        origin.pipe(destination);
    })

    .catch(function (err) {
            console.log("Error: "+err)
    });
```

here for using .then property , a promise is returned. but why?
Would you please explain the functionality of promise and using scope of promise. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This probably changed with age. In the old days, `Promise` had to be imported from a library, nowadays it is a native global that's built into the environment. Check the docs of the node.js version you are using. (Any recent one should not need an extra lib).

Comment: And no, you never need to import `promise` to have a `.then` method on the objects that other code returns. You only need to import the variable if you actually want to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a `Promise` to exist, you don't have to have initialised it, so where you have the chain of `.then`, it works because `dboper.insertDocument` returns a Promise.

e.g. inside `doper`

```
function insertDocument() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // do some stuff
    // resolve
  });
}
```

This allows you to call `.then` on the result of `insertDocument()`.

The other thing you asked is why they are chainable, and that is because `.then` will always return a Promise, no matter what you do inside of it.

e.g.

```
insertDocument()
  .then(() => {
    // do something
    // returning a string rather than a promise
    return 'hello';
  })
  .then(result => {
    // The promise will put the result of the previous function in here
    // even though it wasn't a promise
    console.log(result); // hello
  })
  .then(result => {
    // You can still call .then again, even though nothing was returned
    // from the previous block, but this time result will be undefined
    console.log(result); // undefined
  })
```

Comment: I think I could not clear my problem. sorry about that. I repeat, can i use .then or use promise without using the word "promise"?

Comment: `Promise` is now built into javascript, so you don't need to import any modules to use it. The only reason you would need a library is for older javascript versions, or if you wanted extra features. So you can use promises without importing it. You can also call `.then` on a function that uses Promises or async/await, so **yes** you can use `.then` without using the word "promise".

Comment: thnks a lot. now it is quite clear to me. one more thing what is the extra thinngs u mentioned "if you wanted extra features" ? and would you please give me some easy and effective example of promise in mongoose ?? thanks is advance.